Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe after using startActionPane in Slidable flutter
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
Slidable(
  key: ValueKey(p),
  closeOnScroll: false,
  startActionPane: startAction == plannedRoutes!.indexOf(p) ? ActionPane(
    extentRatio: 0.50,
    motion: ScrollMotion(),
    children: [
      SlidableAction(
        onPressed: (context) async {
            int statusId = p.rpVisitStatusId!;
            if (p.rpVisitStatusId! < 3) {
              if(_isMounted) {
                setState(() {
                  isStatusChanged = true;
                });
              }
              try {
                Provider.of<PatientProvider>(
                    context, listen: false)
                    .updateRpVisitStatus(
                    context, p.visitId!,
                    p.rpVisitStatusId! + 1).then((value) async {
                  plannedRoutes![plannedRoutes!.indexOf(p)]
                      .rpVisitStatusId = value;
                  print("Hello1 $value");
                  if (value == 2) {
                    Patient temp = Patient(
                        firstName: p.firstName!,
                        lastName: p.lastName!,
                        patientCode: p.patientCode!,
                        genderId: -1,
                        age: p.age!);
                    temp.createdDate =
                        DateTime.now().toIso8601String();
                    temp.patientVisitId = p.visitId;
                    temp.serviceTypeId = p.serviceTypeId;
                    temp.sectionTypeId = p.serviceTypeId;
                    temp.visitStatus = VISIT_IN_DRAFT;

                    Provider.of<
                        PatientProvider>(
                        context, listen: false)
                        .savePatientDataToLocalDb(context, temp)
                        .then((value) {
                      temp.patientOfflineId = value;
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  AddServiceTypeScreen(
                                      serviceTypeId: temp
                                          .serviceTypeId,
                                      patient: temp)));
                    });
                  } else {
                    if(_isMounted) {
                      setState(() {
                        plannedRoutes;
                        isStatusChanged = false;
                      });
                    }
                  }
                });
              } catch (error) {
                print("Error Updating status $error");
              }
            }

        },

        backgroundColor: p.rpVisitStatusId == 0 ? Colors.green : p.rpVisitStatusId == 1 ? Colors.orange : primaryColor,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        label: p.rpVisitStatusId == 0 ? 'Start' : p.rpVisitStatusId == 1 ? 'Arrived' : "In Progress",
      ),
    ],
  ) : null,
  
  child: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (contextB,constraints){
      AnimationController animationController = AnimationController(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), vsync: this);
      Slidable.of(contextB)!.actionPaneType.addListener(() {
        if (Slidable.of(contextB)!.actionPaneType.value == ActionPaneType.none) {
          animationController.reverse();
        }else{
          animationController.forward();
        }
      });
      return InkWell(
        child: Container(
          height: p.rpVisitStatusId == 4 ? 70 : 140,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                flex: 8,
                child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 8),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      border: Border.all(color: p.rpVisitStatusId == 1 ? primaryColor : Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular((10))),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: p.rpVisitStatusId! > 0 && p.rpVisitStatusId! < 4 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                          offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0), //(x,y)
                          blurRadius: 6.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 40,
                          height: 60,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(50)),
                          ),
                          // child: Icon(Icons.pin_drop_sharp, size: 40, color: hueList[plannedRoutes!.indexOf(p)],),
                          child: p.rpVisitStatusId == 4 ? Image.asset("assets/images/app_launcher.png", color: Colors.grey) :
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text("${index+1}", style: TextStyle(color: primaryColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                              Image.asset("assets/images/house.png", width: 40),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);


Could you provide a minimum code sample (a mini-applet that contains all imports, classes, etc. ?) - others cannot run your code without having access to the providers you are using, etc. Alternatively if you can't/won't provide them, you could create another code segment that doesn't use the other dependencies but still exhibits the same error you're grappling with.

Note: You may edit your post with additional/changed code if you want to provide another sample.
